# How to close overlay on background click

Tags: 7, modal-dialogs

Please help me to make overlay closed on background click. I am trying with following code but it is not working:

```
jQuery('.overlay-modal-background').live('click', function(e) {
  Drupal.overlay.close();
});
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. "it is not working" is both most popular and most useless report in IT. Does it parse at all? Does it throw any errors? What errors? Is it executed? Please explain *how* it fails. Also, see [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722). Is this code proper Drupal behavior? How do you include it in your page?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Default jQuery from Drupal or using [JQuery Update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module? `live()` method is introduced in jQuery 1.7

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. Nope, `live()` was _deprecated_ in 1.7

Comment: @Clive you're right, I've mistaken it for `on()` method.